# How can I resolve this iCloud Error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, icloud

Hi I am trying to get my core data app syncing to iCloud so that multiple devices can be used.

I just started a new iCloud account for testing and installed my app on both devices. I have enabled my app for iCloud using instructions at this link [Using CoreData with icloud](http://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/452) and by also comparing my app to apple's coreDataRecipes example code.

I was not getting any syncing occurring so I did some logs to find out what was occurring. After adding an object to core data from iPad A i received the following log on iPad B which was connected to the computer.

```
2012-01-20 17:35:35.979 My-App[407:22d7] AppDelegate Merge Changes From iCloud Notifications
2012-01-20 17:35:35.980 My-App[407:22d7] AppDelegate managed Object Context
2012-01-20 17:35:35.981 My-App[407:707] Block redirecting to method merge icloud changes for context
2012-01-20 17:35:35.981 My-App[407:707] AppDelegate Merge icloud changes for context
```

Then I get this error

```
2012-01-20 17:10:48.030 MyApp[407:4c0b] -[PFUbiquityBaseline loadBaselineArchiveWithError:](347): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x387e80>
ubiquityRootLocation: (null)
storeName: (null)
modelVersionHash: (null)
baselineArchiveLocation: (null)

Coordinated read of baseline archive file: (null) did not succed: (null)
2012-01-20 17:10:48.030 MyApp[407:4c0b] -[PFUbiquityBaselineRecoveryOperation resolveConflictsForBaseline:withError:](186): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Baseline conflict resolution had trouble initializing a conflicting baseline version: <PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x387e80>
ubiquityRootLocation: (null)
storeName: (null)
modelVersionHash: (null)
baselineArchiveLocation: (null)

Error: (null)
2012-01-20 17:10:48.031 MyApp[407:4c0b] -[PFUbiquityBaselineRecoveryOperation main](363): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to resolve conflicts for baseline: <PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x1e35a0>
ubiquityRootLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1f2570>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/MYINDIVIDUALID~MyCompany~My_App/invoices
storeName: My-App.store
modelVersionHash: ~4YoLQdnNoouIPvgFerSqmhFoHPk97Clf3AK_rtWHiY=
baselineArchiveLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1e1470>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/MYINDIVIDUALID~MyCompany~My_App/invoices/.baseline/My-App.store/~4YoLQdnNoouIPvgFerSqmhFoHPk97Clf3AK_rtWHiY=/baseline.zip
, the baseline will not be adopted.
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could let me know why I am getting a conflict due to the (null) values and where I can look to resolve this.

Thanks

ps. I have changed the seen in the log app name, unique identifier and company name just for this post.

**EDIT**
Syncing is occurring however it seems to be delayed.

Comment: have u found the ans , if yes then plz update

Comment: some news on this issue, i have it on iOS5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@coder007 I submitted a question to apple about this. They wrote back and said that I should submit a bug report and they credited my question back to me. To be honest I haven't yet had the time submit the bug report, so if you can then it may be the way to go. It must be a problem with iCloud that needs ironing out

**Update**

I Don't have this error anymore, I think apple is gradually improving and eliminating issues with iCloud. I don't think it is a problem on the developers end in terms of coding from my perspective.