# iCloud error messages when launching app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icloud

I sometimes get the following messages immediatly after start up, and when I do, everything in my database appears twice. Anyone ever had a similar problem?

```
-[_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter rollResponseOperation:encounteredAnError:whileTryingToAdoptBaseline:](1509): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquityBaselineRollResponseOperation: 0x1f04b5e0> localPeerID: mobile.10F7B7AF-41F5-547A-8D05-AD22C7A527B4, storeName: iCloudStore, modelVersionHash: oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=
    ubiquityRootLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1ddf5910>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData

Encountered an error while trying to respond to the roll of baseline: <PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x2022ee70>(0)
    permanentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1dde1c50>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=/baseline.zip
    safeLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x20231cd0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=/mobile.10F7B7AF-41F5-547A-8D05-AD22C7A527B4
    currentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1dde1c50>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=/baseline.zip

    storeName: iCloudStore
    modelVersionHash: oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=
    baselineArchiveLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1dde1c50>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=/baseline.zip

Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134310 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134310.)" UserInfo=0x1f192f70 {baseline=<PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x2022ee70>(0)
    permanentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1dde1c50>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=/baseline.zip
    safeLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x20231cd0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=/mobile.10F7B7AF-41F5-547A-8D05-AD22C7A527B4
    currentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1dde1c50>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=/baseline.zip

    storeName: iCloudStore
    modelVersionHash: oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=
    baselineArchiveLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1dde1c50>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=/baseline.zip
, localStoreKV=<PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x1f193460> ()}
userInfo: {
    baseline = "<PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x2022ee70>(0)
    permanentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1dde1c50>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=/baseline.zip
    safeLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x20231cd0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=/mobile.10F7B7AF-41F5-547A-8D05-AD22C7A527B4
    currentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1dde1c50>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=/baseline.zip\n
    storeName: iCloudStore
    modelVersionHash: oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=
    baselineArchiveLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1dde1c50>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/Y5CSSRAZ49~com~myappname/iCloudData/.baseline/iCloudStore/oCxAtFI41bNZlKPPrX91oHYeaXwl_1Bdzlu4QIui2wQ=/baseline.zip\n";
    localStoreKV = "<PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x1f193460> ()";
}
```

Comment: Google search yields this thread: http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=242&t=5411 where someone says they got past if by deleting the app from the device, cleaning the project and rebuilding. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There is also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937805/how-can-i-resolve-this-icloud-error

Comment: @CuriousRabbit Thanks for you answer. I found those two links too, and tried removing/reinstalling everything, it didn't help though. The thing is, I can't really reproduce the error, it just happens every now and then...